# Creating a new field with if else statement in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a new field based on an if else statement.  Basically, I have a "date" field and an "estimated date" field.  I want to create a new field that calculates the difference (days) between a single event and either the date or estimated date field (if date is NA):

```
data <- data.frame("DOD" = c("2020-11-09","2020-01-01","2020-11-19",NA), "DOD.est" = c(NA,NA,NA,"2020-02-09"), "event" = c("Thing1","Thing2","Thing3","Thing4"),"eventDate" = c("2019-02-19","2017-08-09",NA,"2019-12-09"))

data$DOD <- as.Date(data$DOD, "%Y-%m-%d")
data$DOD.est <- as.Date(data$DOD.est, "%Y-%m-%d")
data$eventDate <- as.Date(data$eventDate, "%Y-%m-%d")

# If DOD not NA, calculate diff using DOD.  If DOD NA and DOD.est is not NA, use DOD.est to calculate diff
if (!is.na(data$DOD)) {
  data$event_to_death <- as.numeric(data$DOD - data$eventDate) 
} else if (is.na(data$DOD) & !is.na(data$DOD.est)) {
  data$event_to_death <- as.numeric(data$DOD.est - data$eventDate)
}
```

My result:

```
DOD           DOD.est        event       eventDate       event_to_death
2020-11-09    NA             Thing1      2019-02-19       629
2020-01-01    NA             Thing2      2017-08-09       875
2020-11-19    NA             Thing3      NA               NA
NA            2020-02-09     Thing4      2019-12-09       NA
```

For the last row, I would expect the event_to_death to have a calculation since DOD is NA and DOD.est is not NA.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with `ifelse()` which is vectorized. Function `if()` works well for individual values, and can raise issues when working over variables. In that case is better to use `ifelse`. Here the code as an option for you:

```
#Code
data$event_to_death <- ifelse(!is.na(data$DOD),as.numeric(data$DOD - data$eventDate),
                              ifelse(is.na(data$DOD) & !is.na(data$DOD.est),
                                     as.numeric(data$DOD.est - data$eventDate),NA))
```

Output:

```
data
         DOD    DOD.est  event  eventDate event_to_death
1 2020-11-09       <NA> Thing1 2019-02-19            629
2 2020-01-01       <NA> Thing2 2017-08-09            875
3 2020-11-19       <NA> Thing3       <NA>             NA
4       <NA> 2020-02-09 Thing4 2019-12-09             62
```

In order to get your solution working, you need to tell `if()` that conditions need to be evaluated at value level (each row) because the function if a vector is found, it uses to evaluate the condition only for certain values. You will need a loop:

```
#Variable
data$event_to_death <- NA
#Loop
for(i in 1:nrow(data))
{
  if (!is.na(data$DOD[i])) {
    data$event_to_death[i] <- as.numeric(data$DOD[i] - data$eventDate[i]) 
  } else if (is.na(data$DOD[i]) & !is.na(data$DOD.est[i])) {
    data$event_to_death[i] <- as.numeric(data$DOD.est[i] - data$eventDate[i])
  } 
}
```

Output:

```
data
         DOD    DOD.est  event  eventDate event_to_death
1 2020-11-09       <NA> Thing1 2019-02-19            629
2 2020-01-01       <NA> Thing2 2017-08-09            875
3 2020-11-19       <NA> Thing3       <NA>             NA
4       <NA> 2020-02-09 Thing4 2019-12-09             62
```

In that way, conditions are evaluated by each value, and `if()` works properly.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.  But, why doesn't it work with the if else statement?

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 It is because `if` works at individual value level. I will add a skecth of how to get working your code!

Comment: @DiamondJoe12 I have added an update, explaining what happens with your code, and how to get it working. Let me know if that works and if it is clear!

Comment: Thanks!  Working now!